# NEST Elastic Search: Difference between FilterInputs term and terms?

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest, filter-input

```
FilterInputs mustfilters;
mustfilters &= ms.Term("cityId", filterInputs.cities);
mustfilters &= ms.Terms("cityIds", filterInputs.cities);
```

What would difference be between above 2 lines?

As far i have tested, the second will allow multiple cities in document with kye cityIds. Any if any matches with filterInputs.cities=> record is returned.

While first will only allow once city.If it matches=>record return else not.

Please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Term` allows to match only one term. According to documentation:

> The term query finds documents that contain the exact term specified in the inverted index.

See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.x/query-dsl-term-query.html)

while `Terms` allows you to specify multiple terms and match any of them.It works like `in` in `Sql` . According to documentation:

> Terms Query Filters documents that have fields that match any of the provided terms (not analyzed).

See [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html)